# How to "call a return value" in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I just learned to program in Prolog. It's very confusing because I don't know how to "call a returned value" as in other languages.

For example, I wrote a predicate findVar(L,R) which means R is the list of all the variables in list L. Now I want to write a predicate findLength(L,Len) to find the length of list R (the result of findVar(L,R)). How do I connect to List R here? Thanks!

```
findLength([],0).
findLength([H|T],Len) :-
   findLength(T,TailLen),
   Len is TailLen+1.
```

Comment: What's wrong with: `findVar(L, R), findLength(R, Len).`?

Comment: Because this step is a middle step of a problem so I am not supposed to do it in query. Can I link findVar(L,R) in findLength?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, *this step is a middle step of a problem*. What you asked for (*I want to write a predicate `findLength(L,Len)` to find the length of list R (the result of `findVar(L,R))`*) is exactly solved by `findVar(L, R), length(R, Len)` (`length/2` actually already exists and you don't have to write `findLength/2`). You can write that conjunction of two queries *in the middle* of a sequence of other queries.